# How do I resolve "undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>"?

Tags: c++, include, sfml, libs

Well I'm trying to install SFML for C++ and it's giving me horrific log crashes... I linked and put all the paths for the compiler and the linker and Buid Log is giving me that:

```
GLCheck.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& 

std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
GLCheck.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
GLCheck.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
GLCheck.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<unsigned long>(unsigned long)'|
GLCheck.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
GLCheck.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
GLCheck.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
GLCheck.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
GLCheck.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'|
GLCheck.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
GLCheck.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
GLCheck.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<unsigned long>(unsigned long)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<unsigned long>(unsigned long)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<unsigned long>(unsigned long)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<unsigned long>(unsigned long)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<unsigned long>(unsigned long)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<unsigned long>(unsigned long)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Texture.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Shader.cpp||more undefined references to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)' follow|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
Shader.cpp||undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build finished: 50 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds) ===|
```

I have tried that links: -lminwg32, and nothing happens. What can I do?

Comment: `undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>` -- Fix the undefined reference.

Comment: I'm guessing your compiler is GCC, since you mention "mingw" in passing. Are you by any chance linking with `gcc` or `ld` itself? You'll need to link with `g++` to get the C++ runtime library.

Comment: Before was mingw-g++.exe I have change to g++.exe (g++.exe -LC:\SFML-2.1\Build\lib  -o bin\Release\abc.exe obj\Release\main.o   -s  -lmingw32 -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-audio-s -lsfml-network-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lopengl32 -lglu32 ) but nothing new happens... :( And yes I was searching in Google if that was the problem, and not is the problem... :/

Comment: It is quite clear that you are not linking with the C++ standard library - are you sure there isn't some other error just before this long list, such as "can't find library something.lib" (or "something.a"), which would inidicate that the libraries are in the wrong place/incorrectly installed etc. Have you tried just building a standard "hello world" program?

Comment: With SFML or without that?

Comment: Without SFML I don't have any problem... With SFML I have that problem (code): http://pastebin.com/AHtZvVS0